# cordova - "x-ms-webview" access dom elements to perform login

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-10, cordova-plugins

Is there any chance to access the dom elements of a "x-ms-webview" ? For my cordova application, I want to use a custom login page. That's why I need to load a webview in the background, access the login fields and "click" the submit button via javascript.

For iOS and the UIWebview this working (I could not believe) really smooth and nice. Is there any chance to realize this for windows 10 as well ? This is what I have so far (not really much):

```
    function onWebviewLoadedLoginPage(ev) {
        webview.removeEventListener("MSWebViewDOMContentLoaded", onWebviewLoadedPage);

        // --> Here I need to access the dom elements of the loaded webview !? 

    }

    var webview = document.createElement("x-ms-webview");
    document.body.appendChild(webview);
    webview.addEventListener("MSWebViewDOMContentLoaded", onWebviewLoadedPage);
    webview.navigate(url);
```

In objective-c I can set the login credentials directly to the dom elements quite easy:

```
 NSString* statement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').value = '%@'", self->usernameInputFieldId, self->username];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:statement];
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Have you found a solution? Was there a reason not to use InAppBrowser and injectScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you need to execute javascript inside the webview once the content is loaded. In that case, you can use `invokeScriptAsync` method of the webview element. `invokeScriptAsyc` accepts two parameters a function's name and that function's parameters. However, It can only call a javascript function that is written inside the webview. However, `eval()` is used to execute javascript code that is written in form of string. Hence to execute your javascript code your function should be:

```
function onWebviewLoadedLoginPage(ev) {
    webview.removeEventListener("MSWebViewDOMContentLoaded", onWebviewLoadedPage);

    // --> Here I need to access the dom elements of the loaded webview !? 
    var javascriptcode = "document.getElementByID('#myelement')"; // Your javascript code in the form of string

    var injectedJavascript = webview.invokeScriptAsync('eval', javascriptcode);
    injectedJavascript.start();

}
```